# How to use no argument function on dask graph?

Tags: dask

I know how to call a function with args using dask graph, but I am not able to call a function without any args. This just return a function itself, not a result of call.

```py
dsk = {'res': ask}
dask.get(dsk, 'res')
```

Could you suggest me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, it should be called in such a way;

```py
dsk = {'res': (ask,)}
dask.get(dsk, 'res')
```

as a tuple of function name and empty.